# How to playing youtube remote video urls on google tv for my android app

Tags: google-tv

Iam new to developing apps on google tv.I want to run my android movies app in google tv.So,how to develop my movies app on google tv and playing youtube movies from given remote url when click list of mvies in google tv.Please give the suggesstions or sample code

Answer (score 1):

See Google TV Developer guide:

[https://developers.google.com/tv/android/](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_demo_samples)

and sample apps:

> https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_demo_samples